# Can a witness server be a witness for more than one pair of mirrored servers?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, mirroring

In the interest of saving time and money (licenses).

For example:

We have a mirrored SharePoint backend as well as a mirrored Lync SQL backend.

I want to use the witness for the Lync servers to be the witness for the SharePoint mirrored pair at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason why it can't be done. In fact, Microsoft documentation states that [one server can be a witness to multiple sessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175191.aspx#InMultipleSessions).

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the confirmation and link, mustaccio!